# How to display only the top 10 strongest correlated variables with corrplot() in R?

Tags: r, correlation, r-corrplot

I have > 100 variables and would like to understand how they are correlated with each other. I would like to do this using the `corrplot()` function from the `corrplot` package.

`corrplot()` offers the option to order the displayed variables so that the most strongly correlated variables get displayed in the top right of the corrplot. The parameter `order="hclust"` has to be set to achieve this:

```
library(corrplot)
corrplot(cor(df), order="hclust", type="upper") # df = data.frame object
```

**Problem:** The `corrplot` will contain all > 100 variables and is hence not readable. Therefore, I am looking for a way to display the top 10 strongest correlated variables in a `corrplot`, then the top 11-20 in another `corrplot`, etc. I am grateful for your tips and advice. Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Although I'm one year late, I'll leave this here in case someone else needs this simple and beautiful solution:

Install **lares** from GitHub

```
devtools::install_github("laresbernardo/lares")
```

Barchart with top correlations in dataset

```
library(lares) 
corr_cross(data_frame, # dataset
           max_pvalue = 0.05, # show only sig. correlations at selected level
           top = 10 # display top 10 correlations, any couples of variables  )
```

Barchart with top corellations focused on only one variable (happy)

```
corr_var(data_frame, # dataset
         happy, # name of variable to focus on
         top = 10 # display top 10 correlations )
```

Answer (score 1):

We can create a grouping variable based on the correlation coefficient after `arrange`ing the correlation values in descending order and removing the duplicate elements

```
library(tidyverse)
n1 <- 10 
m1 <- cor(df)
out <- as.table(m1) %>%
        as_data_frame %>% 
        transmute(Var1N = pmin(Var1, Var2), Var2N = pmax(Var1, Var2), n) %>% 
        distinct %>% 
        filter(Var1N != Var2N) %>% 
        arrange(desc(n)) %>%
        group_by(grp = as.integer(gl(n(), n1, n())))
```

Based on the grouping variable, we can do the `corrplot` individually for each set of groups

```
posplt <- possibly(function(x) 
           corrplot(x, order = "hclust", type = "upper"), otherwise = NA)
pdf("corplt.pdf")
out[1:3] %>% 
      split(out$grp) %>% 
      map(~ xtabs(n ~ Var1N + Var2N, .x) %>% 
                 posplt) 
dev.off()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that seems to work. out is a tibble which I can then filter with e.g. filter(out, grp == 2) to get the variables with correlation ranking 11-20. The "n" in your tibble is the pearson correlation coefficient? Do you have any references that would help me understand your code better (I am new to tidyverse). Thank you so much.

Comment: @JFK Here, I created a grouping variable based on the `n1` ie. it will group the first 10 most correlated to one group, then the next 10 to second and so on.   The output of `cor` is a matrix, and I converted it to a data.frame/tbl ('long' format), then removed the mirror duplicate elements before doing the `arrange` of 'n' in descending order (correlation values).  Once, it is done, I plotted the individual sets of correlations into a `pdf` file.

Comment: You can also filter out individual sets with `filter`

Comment: The only drawback of your solution is that one cannot use the out result or the filtered out result, e.g. filter(out, grp == 2) as input into a corrplot.

Comment: @JFK  If you check my second set of code, I created a matrix with `xtabs` so, if you do `out2 <- filter(out, grp == 2); m2 <- xtabs(n ~ Var1N + Var2N, out2)` and this can be used in the `corrplot` I wrapped with `possibly` for cases that are not square matrix

Comment: Thank you so much. I would like to give an upvote, however I can't because of < 15 reputation.